# How to call the getPhoneId () Method of TelephonyManager

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I trying to get the phoneId through the following code:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = 
(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
int phoneId=telephonyManager.getPhoneId(SubscriptionManager. 
getDefaultSubscriptionId())
```

But I am getting the Following Error:
Error:The PhoneId method is undefined in TelephonyManager
Help me to get the PhoneId.

Actually I want to call

- @hide */

  ```
  public static int getDefaultVoicePhoneId() {
      return getPhoneId(getDefaultVoiceSubscriptionId());
  }
  ```

  Which is hidden,so I was using the above piece of code in which I got the error

Comment: Looks like that method was removed years ago.  You can probably use `getSubscriberId()`

Comment: @Daniel Nugent I have used that too also but still getting the same error.